# How to fix httpd: Syntax error on line 259 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: </Directory>#> directive missing closing '>'

Tags: apache2

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 259 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: </Directory>#> directive missing closing '>'
```

Comment: Please show the command you ran that gave this output

Answer (score 1):

As error shows you have missed `>` sign on exact 259 line number of apache conf file.
You can fix it by adding it and run `apachectl -k` command to check configuration. You will see `Syntax OK`, once you have fixed error.